# trigrams with all the words as unique python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe where one of the column contains list of Trigrams. The dataframe is huge.

df:

```
val    Trigrams
 1     ['status opportunity reference', 'reject remove reject', 'situation situation hon', 'Good Sure Cable']
 2     ['don bradman sir', 'manners maketh man', 'gold chain chain'']
```

Below mentioned is a sample row value of the Trigram column:

```
['status opportunity reference', 'reject remove reject', 'situation situation hon', 'Good Sure Cable']
```

If you see the 2nd element `"reject remove reject"` the first word is equal to 3rd word.

If  you see the 3rd element `"situation situation hon"` first word is equal to 2nd word.

What I'm looking for is **removing such trigrams from the list** and **keeping only those trigrams where all the 3 words are unique**.

In this case the output would be:

```
['status opportunity reference', 'Good Sure Cable']
```

I have written a custom for loop:

```
new_list = []
for trigram in list_of_trigrams:
    if trigram[0] != trigram[1] and trigram[1] != trigram[2] and trigram[0]!=trigram[2]:
        new_list.append(trigram)
```

And converting this logic to UDF i can use .apply function in pandas to get the output. But this isn't a correct way, as I have to do it for millions of rows.

What I'm looking for is a pythonic way of doing this, quickly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'val':[1,2],
                   'Trigrams': [['status opportunity reference', 'reject remove reject', 'situation situation hon', 'Good Sure Cable'],
                                ['don bradman sir', 'manners maketh man', 'gold chain chain']]}, 
                  )
```

---

```
df['Trigrams'] = [[y for y in x if len(set(y.split())) == 3] for x in df['Trigrams']]
```

alternative:

```
df['Trigrams'] = df['Trigrams'].apply(lambda x: [y for y in x if len(set(y.split())) == 3])
```

---

```
print(df)
   val                                         Trigrams
0    1  [status opportunity reference, Good Sure Cable]
1    2            [don bradman sir, manners maketh man]
```

**Performance** for 200k rows:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'val':[1,2],
                   'Trigrams': [['status opportunity reference', 'reject remove reject', 'situation situation hon', 'Good Sure Cable'],
                                ['don bradman sir', 'manners maketh man', 'gold chain chain']]}, 
                  )
df = pd.concat([df] * 100000, ignore_index=True)


df['Trigrams1'] = [[y for y in x if len(set(y.split())) == 3] for x in df['Trigrams']]
df['Trigrams2'] = df['Trigrams'].apply(lambda x: [y for y in x if len(set(y.split())) == 3])



In [96]: %timeit df['Trigrams1'] = [[y for y in x if len(set(y.split())) == 3] for x in df['Trigrams']]
627 ms ± 30.9 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [97]: %timeit df['Trigrams2'] = df['Trigrams'].apply(lambda x: [y for y in x if len(set(y.split())) == 3])
520 ms ± 4.97 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: I've posted sample dataframe.

Comment: @ShubhamR - added 2 solutions to answer.

Comment: @ShubhamR - From testing `apply` solution is faster, is possible test in your real data?

Answer (score 1):

One approach

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    [[['status opportunity reference', 'reject remove reject', 'situation situation hon', 'Good Sure Cable']],
     [['don bradman sir', 'manners maketh man', 'gold chain chain']]], columns=["trigrams"])
res = [[trigram for trigram in trigrams if len(set(trigram.split())) == 3] for trigrams in df["trigrams"]]
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
[['status opportunity reference', 'Good Sure Cable'], ['don bradman sir', 'manners maketh man']]
```

Comment: Working, but if I convert this into a function and apply it on a dataframe, will it be fast?

Comment: @ShubhamR Didn't realize the question was about pandas, updated the answer with a pandas solution

Comment: No No, the dataframe is incorrect. My bad, let me post a sample dataframe. the list which I mentioned is in the same row.